# Missing parameters in my rack Ableton Live

Tags: sound-effects, ableton-live

[image]

Hey guys, i am missing the part where the gain and all those other 8 parameters are. Do you know why and how i can open it? 
See screen shot for explanation. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the top picture, you have a simpler > inside an instrument rack > inside a drum rack.
In the bottom picture you have a simpler > inside a drum rack...  If you select this simpler and hit cmd-g you'll group it into an instrument rack and you'll be able to access this layer of macros.
J.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me out! Much appreciated! unfortunately it didn't work. I didn't get the gain, attack etc parameters to come up. It was just stacked into an instrument rack, like you said but no gain , attack parameters were added. Do you know any other possible solution?

Comment: Ask this question on the Ableton Live forum perhaps? This is not a sound design question..

Comment: In the simpler on the right side is a circular arrow. Press it to Open the Parameter Marcos. Then you can Map them to gain etc

Answer (score 1):

.." I didn't get the gain, attack etc parameters to come up"

The parameters you are looking for must be assigned manually. I guess the nested Drum/Instrument/Simpler rack in the upper part of your picture is a factory preset.